# Suitable layout for grid of buttons in android

Tags: android

I am confused with the appropriate layout design to be used for grid of buttons. I want to display a "textview and EditText" at the top. Below that there should be a 3*4 grid/matrix of 12 buttons(like cell phone keys), following another three linear buttons at the bottom of the root layout. (upper layout should not overlap the bottom buttons).

It would be of great help if anybody guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UI layouts are done using xml files. Read about it before you start](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

While this is not exactly what [you want here is a something to get you going](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/res/layout/?r=24).

Comment: @ Reno: Thanks a lot ! It will help me a lot.